# @media query to target hi-res Windows Phone 8+?

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, media-queries

According to [Brett Jankord's Cross Browser Retina/High Resolution Media Queries](http://www.brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/)

> Windows 8 phones do not support any of the device-pixel-ratio media queries.

Is there another way to target windows phones with css?

(I don't mind if all windows phones get the hi-res images)

Comment: Adding CSS and CSS3 tags suddendly raised your audience from 610 to 32.000 readers ;)

Answer (score 1):

The article then goes on saying that IE does support `min-resolution` but only with `dpi`

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Sadly the reported resolution is 96dpi, instead of the real 306 PPI. I'm not sure if that microsoft fault or the manufacturer. Reminds me of http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: you are right, there is a possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654425/detecting-hidpi-windows-phone-8-devices#answer-14658515